# Microsoft Visual Studio - 'The build tools for v140 cannot be found'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When trying to run some previous code today i was presented with the above error, i am using Visual Studio 2013 and have not been able to solve my issue when browsing similar questions on this site. I tried upgrading to 2015 and that did not fix the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2013 comes with the `v120` platform toolset, so that error is expected if that's all you have installed.

Installing VS 2015 will put the `v140` platform toolset on your system, but note that the 'typical' install of VS 2015 does not include C++. You have to use the 'custom' install to add it. See [Setup Changes in Visual Studio 2015 Affecting C++ Developers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/).

Related: [Visual Studio 2015 RTM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/07/24/visual-studio-2015-rtm/), [Update 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/11/30/visual-studio-2015-update-1/), [Update 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2016/03/31/visual-studio-2015-update-2/)